Inkscape Offset LPE insets wrong
So in Inkscape I'm trying to use the Offset LPE to inset a path, but it gives a weird interpolation. 
My desired result is in blue, and the original path is in red. 
Is there a workaround to get the blue path?

I'm using Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25)

The Offset Path effect is really designed to be used on a closed path, not an open path.  If you try to use it on an open path, and drag the offset control outwards, it will work, but if you try to drag it inwards, it's going to give you an unexpected result.


ah I see.. is there a sort of workaround though?

@sourapple well, you could make it a closed path, like a rectangle/square, and apply a clipping mask after applying the offset path effect to clip the excess.
